# VSCode IntelliSense thinks a Python 'function()' class exists

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, pylance

VSCode / IntelliSense is completing a Python class called `function()` that does not appear to exist.

For example, this appears to be valid code:

```
def foo(value):
    return function(value)

foo(0)
```

But `function` is not defined in this scope, so running this raises a `NameError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hayesall/wip.py", line 4, in <module>
    foo(0)
  File "/home/hayesall/wip.py", line 2, in foo
    return function(value)
NameError: name 'function' is not defined
```

I expected IntelliSense to warn me about `function` being undefined. `function()` does not appear to have a docstring, and I cannot find anything about it in the wider Python/CPython/VSCode documentation. (*Side note*: `pylint` recognizes "Undefined variable 'function'").

What is `function()`? Or: is there an explanation for why IntelliSense is matching this?

---

**Screenshots**:

Writing the word `function` provides an autocomplete:

[image: Screenshot of vscode, with a def foo like the code listing above. VSCode is autocompleting the name function as a Python class with no documentation.]

---

`function` is not defined in this scope, but IntelliSense seems to *think* that it is:

[image: The same listing as before, and VSCode has not indicated that function is undefined.]

---

Some version info:

```
Debian
code 1.75.1 (x86)
Pylance v2023.2.30
Python 3.9.15 (CPython, GCC 11.2.0)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question to hopefully clarify. Either: (1) Is there actually a `function()` object in Python that IntelliSense is picking up on? or (2) Is this unexpected IntelliSense behavior?

Comment: e.g.: "Going to definition" seems to be referencing `builtins.pyi`, which in 3.9 at least has a comment saying: "Doesn't exist at runtime, but deleting this breaks mypy. See #2999"

Comment: IntelliSense is acquired through typeshed. The problems you encounter have been raised by many people in [github](https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/7580). They hope to delete the class **function**. You can continue to pay attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function` class is type of function (functions are objects in `python`), consider that

```
def return_one():
    return 1
print(type(return_one))
```

gives output

```
<class 'function'>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't make that connection. Small followup: do you know if there is a reason for this type not existing at runtime? e.g. do you know a recommended way to do: `isinstance(return_one, function)`? (My bad if this is too broad, I probably need to read or ask a separate question).

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes take look at [`inspect.isfunction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isfunction)